# Device prompt appears under app pop overs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I have a problem with the app I'm working on. This image will explain what.

[image]

As you can see, the "low battery notification prompt" appears under the date picker. This also happens when I have an action sheet active on display in my app and then a "new message prompt" appears when somebody texted me. In my code i called the action sheet to display in view.

```
 [self.view addSubview:datePickerView];//Where I add date picker
 [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];//Where I add the action sheet
```

In action sheet I also tried

```
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

I don't have an idea how to fix this since Im new in iOS. I hope one can help.

Thanks!